# Malliavin derivative of stopped Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

Let $B_t$ stand for the standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Denote
$$T = \inf\{t| \|B_t\| = 1\}.$$
That is, $T$ is the first exit time from the unit ball.

I am interested in calculating the Malliavin derivative $DB_T$.
The immediate suspect is $DB_T = 1_{[0,T]}$.
I could not prove it though and I suspect it is not 100% correct.

Is the functional $B_T$ even Malliavin differentiable? If so, how to obtain the derivative?

Comment: First of all, the derivative should be a $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$-valued process. Further than that, intuitively your suspicion does not seem correct. Suppose you perturb $B_t$ by  $\varepsilon v$, where $\varepsilon$ is infinitesimally small and $v$ is a unit vector. Two things can happen: a) $t>T$, in which case $B_T$ does is not affected b) $t<T$, in which case the exit point changes by $\varepsilon P_T v$, where $P_T$ is the projection to the tangent plane of $B_T$. So my alternative suggested suspicion would be $1_{[0,T]} P_T$.

Answer (score 2):

Stopped Brownian motion is not Malliavin differentiable because if it was it would imply that $T$ is constant (see footnote pg.4 [Locally Lipschitz BSDE driven by a continuous martingale
path-derivative approach](https://www.monash.edu/__data/assets/pdf_file/0011/1194635/10-PathDiff4.pdf)).

We would have that $W_{T}=\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{s\leq T}dW_{s}\in \mathbb{D}^{1,2}$ and $1_{s\leq T}\in \mathbb{D}^{1,2}$. However, by Nualart's proposition 1.2.6 (in "Malliavin and Related topics") we would get that $P[s\leq T]=0$ or $1$.

However, there is some work in [Hitting times for Gaussian processes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606086.pdf) that still manages to get related estimates for hitting times using Malliavin calculus.